# How do you get the assigned group for a ListViewItem in a Coded UI Test?

Tags: winforms, coded-ui-tests

I'm filtering a list of objects and sorting them based upon certain criteria of their properties into various groups in a ListView.  For the Coded UI tests, I generate test data with very specific values.  I need to assert that the test data has been sorted into the correct groups.  I do not see how to get the group object, group name, or anything else that is remotely close.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sample code? That would help us provide a comprehensive answer if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm...  After browsing the Locals window, I have found the base object "[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.WinControls.WinListItem]", which seems to have the correct value in the property "HelpText":

```
    foreach (UITestControl item in uIMedSlipListList.Items)
    {
        WinListItem listItem = item as WinListItem;
        if(listItem != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(listItem.HelpText);
        }

    }
```

Well, it has the text displayed for the group, not the group name, but I can build a working test off of that.

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer to your question or is it additional information. In the former then please clarify that it is indeed an answer. If the latter then please add the information to the original question.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a working solution, which is why I marked it as the answer.